# How to not select duplicated row when primary key is used in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

For a school project in PHP (to simplify it, it's a forum), i've a query to make but it's quite complicated. If you can give my tips, rather than the answers, it would be perfect!

[Here's the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SerYc.png), where a Post (so PostId) can be an answer or a question and if `ParentId == NULL`, then it's a question. Otherwise, the ParentId is the question the post is answered to. 
I'd like to implement a search form but i'm stuck on the query, here's what i've already tried :

```
("SELECT * FROM Post, User WHERE Post.AuthorId = user.UserId and Title LIKE :Body or Body LIKE :Body
UNION
SELECT * FROM Post, User WHERE Post.AuthorId = user.UserId and UserName LIKE :Body 
LIMIT 0, 5", array("Body"=>"%$search%")
```

The problem is that, in the end, if the query selects an answer, I will take it's Parent to show the question, so it can ends in duplicated questions showed. (For example : If the user searched is the author of a question and has also answered to his post, the query will select his first post and his answer : duplicated)

I could make a sort in PHP but, as I'd to like to show 5 results per page, it can't be done that way.

So my question is :
How to not select a Post if it's Parent has already been selected before?

Comment: Sorry I'm trying to get a handle on what the search is trying to look at - are you searching the user, body of the question, body of the answers, anything?

Comment: If it's on the username, anything he has posted (question and answer). Otherwise, if the word (or sentense) appears in the body or in the title (of any post) it's good !

Comment: Sorry it's been a while - been doing other things. I don't have time to make an answer for you, but I would probably look at making a query just for the questions and then use group_concat to create a string which you can LIKE for the answers. 

Alternatively split the problem up into 2 queries and then get a list of ids you can then use for your search results.

If this wasn't a school project I would tell you to look at sphinx - it's a search indexer and a bit more robust/commercial grade search tool.